# QRcode optical recognition in the browser

Tags: browser, webcam, qr-code

What is the state-of-the-art for implementing a fully browser-based application that recognizes QRcodes in sight of the machine's webcam?

I understand that native browser support of webcams in general is still in its infancy.  Have there been notable successes in processing webcam video in the browser?

In particular, is it "technically possible" given current HTML5 technologies to actually get the data of a QRcode from a live webcam image in the browser, WITHOUT making any trips to the server for image processing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Flex/Actionscript with zxing. See here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Factionscript